# Converting QString to LPCWSTR qt c++

Tags: c++, qt

Currently I am attempting to convert a `QString` to a `LPCWSTR` that will be used in `URLDownloadToFile()`. The following is a simple version of my current code:

```
QString url = "http://whatever_file...";
HRESULT hRez = URLDownloadToFile(NULL, (LPCWSTR)url.toLocal8Bit().constData(), TEXT("C:\\etc..."), 0, NULL);
```

The conversion was found working, in the post I found it in, with conversion of `QString` to `LPCWSTR`. I am rather new in the field of programming and I simply added a letter to that solution as `URLDownloadToFile` require it. It return no error however the download fail.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Any reason why you are not using `QtNetwork` module? You can download from `http://` URL easily.

Comment: It was simply more convenient as I previously had used URLDownloadToFile. Perhaps I should look into that instead then... Still, would be ingesting to find out how to do it this way as well...

Comment: `LPCWSTR` is a pointer to a *wide* (i.e. 16-bit char) string; `QString::toLocal8Bit()`, obviously, produces an 8-bit char string. The explicit cast does not change that. You can either convert get the `QString` data as a wide string, or use the narrow version of the function (`URLDownloadToFileA`).

Comment: @AndrewMedico nice I have it working now, thanks xD

Answer (score 3):

To get LPCWSTR from QString you can use [QString::constData](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstring.html#constData) method, because QChar is 2 byte Unicode symbol, exactly as WCHAR (if wchar_t is 2 byte on target machine).

And I aware you from the using of "TEXT" macro in one line with "LPCWSTR". You should use "L" instead.

"TEXT" is created for using in pair with the "LPCTSTR" macro. You can read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/76252/What-are-TCHAR-WCHAR-LPSTR-LPWSTR-LPCTSTR-etc)  about them.